# I am trying to build a formula but it will not work when put together

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to build a formula, but it will not work when put together like: =SUMPRODUCT(E12:E45>D12:D45),COUNTIF(E12:E45,">2.9") 
I need both statements to work together. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does adding parenthese do what you want? `=SUMPRODUCT((E12:E45>D12:D45),COUNTIF(E12:E45,">2.9"))` Or are you trying to do something else? What is your formula attempting to do?

Comment: I need the formula to compare two columns for the greater number and count that number if it is greater than 2.9.

Comment: Like this: =COUNTIF(E12:E45,">2.9") after comparing the two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the formula to compare two columns for the greater number and count that number if it is greater than 2.9

I believe this should do what you are looking for:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E12:E45>D12:D45)*(E12:E45>2.9))
```

This will give a count where both conditions hold.